# Lag in starting coroutine on Dispatchers.Main

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines

**ViewModel.kt**

```
private val viewModelJob = Job()
private val defaultScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default + viewModelJob)

fun sort() {

    defaultScope.launch {

        // sort logic (on tempList)

        Log.d("my_tag", "Sort time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - sortStart))

        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            Log.d("my_tag", "Updating sorted list")
            sortedItemList.value = tempList
        }
    }
}
```

`sortedItemList` is a MutableLiveData in the viewModel, that is being observed in the activity, which in turn prints a log and uses the list to set a recycler view. But whenever I open the activity, I see a lag of around `80 - 300ms` in setting the recycler view, which is quite noticeable. Here's my logcat:

```
2020-06-13 14:46:41.031 22004-22066 D/my_tag: Sort time: 19
2020-06-13 14:46:41.324 22004-22004 D/my_tag: Updating sorted list
2020-06-13 14:46:41.324 22004-22004 D/my_tag: Observe sorted list
```

I think this lag is because `Dispatchers.Main` consists of only the main thread, which may be doing something else, at that time. Isn't it so? And, how should I remove this lag, or have a faster workaround around this? Thanks.

Comment: Try with `Dispatchers.Main.immediate` it'll try to get into the thread ASAP instead of queuing up, but it won't guarantee as there may be a process which is long running (which shouldn't there be) so might work.

Comment: You could do away with the `withContext(Dispatchers.Main) { .. }` block and replace with : `sortedItemList.postValue(tempList)` - which will get the main `Looper` and post the value to a queue much like a `Handler` - this might yield better performance than using coroutines to switch contexts.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu Tried that, didn't show any improvement. And, I ain't doing anything long running on the main thread too.

Comment: @MarkKeen I had tried that in the first place, but got the same kinda lag.

Comment: Then probably under the hood corutines, on Android at least, is probably doing something similar.  I suggest you profile the main thread (or some logging) - if it is doing a lot of heavy work at the time the collection is ready it will block until the call stack returns.  Tip : try delaying the sorting function for a few seconds deliberately (so any UI setup work has completed) and see if you have the same performce lag, if not then the former is probably true - too much work is happening on the main thread on initialisation.

Comment: @MarkKeen See, if I just do `sortedItemList.value = tempList` in the sort() and return, there is no lag. So, I think this lag shouldn't be because of the UI setup work.